# Is there a limit on the number of blobs storable in SQL Server with filestream?

Tags: sql-server, filestream

I use `filestream` to store blobs (files). I use SQL Server 2008 R2

Some customers have 60k files (50GB). They ask me if there is a limit after which, also because of NTFS, there will be problems.

Somehow the doubt is: if the number of blobs grows too much is there a limit beyond which SQL Server will not handle them properly or not?

I think SQL Server handles this well, but does anyone has a better reply?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

60.000 files and 50 GB should be absolutely no problem. You might want to read ["Special Consideration for Large Environments"](http://download.microsoft.com/download/d/9/4/d948f981-926e-40fa-a026-5bfcf076d9b9/FILESTREAM%20Design%20and%20Implementation%20Considerations.docx).

A challenge could be to come up with a recovery plan.